# Why fetch response is a HTML structure and not a JSON object ? how could i directly get my data inside the script tag?

Tags: html, json

This question have already been asked but no real solution was found. so today I'm asking for guidance.

**What has been already said on this forum and didn't work for me:**

- sometimes API return HTML instead of JSON
- adding  this code in fetch didn't work

  ```
  headers:{
  'Accept': 'application/json
  'Content-Type: 'application/json
  }
  ```
- it could be I need to create a sort of login system into my API (the point I can't find how do it  since my API is just an basic html page with data and without any backend)

My API URL render this data (a simple Array of Object): ***https://api--food.web.app/***

**The `response.text()` return this in console :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='container'>
        <div id='output'></div>
    </div>

    <script>
    
        (function createAPI (data){
            var data = [
                {id:"001",code:"123456",name:"Kebab Hazar","cnc":{id:1,url:"react-amulet.com"},address:"3 Rue Grandclément",postalcode:"69100",city:"villeurbanne",
                media:{logo:{small:"https://img.cuisineaz.com/660x660/2015-04-05/i113726-kebab-facile.jpg",big:"https://img.cuisineaz.com/680x357/2016-10-19/i7058-les-allemands-accros-au-kebab.jpg"}},
                text:{presentation:'Kebab Tacos, assiettes ...',opening_time:"Ouvert 7j/7j de 10h00 à 23h00"}},
                {id:"002",code:"100000",name:"Baracca Kebab","cnc":{id:2,url:"react-amulet.com"},address:"21 Avenue Jean Mermoz",postalcode:"69001",city:"Lyon",
                media:{logo:{small:"https://reinformation.tv/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Allemagne-d%C3%B6ner-kebab-normes-e1479925470202.jpg",big:"https://reinformation.tv/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Allemagne-d%C3%B6ner-kebab-normes-e1479925470202.jpg"}},
                text:{presentation:'Kebab Tacos, assiettes ...',opening_time:"Ouvert 7j/7j de 09h00 à 23h00"}},
                {id:"003",code:"100001",name:"Kebab Sultan","cnc":{id:3,url:"react-amulet.com"},address:"21 Avenue Jean Mermoz",postalcode:"69006",city:"Lyon",
                media:{logo:{small:"https://image.freepik.com/vecteurs-libre/modele-mascotte-logo-kebab-sultan_190190-154.jpg",big:"https://image.freepik.com/vecteurs-libre/modele-mascotte-logo-kebab-sultan_190190-154.jpg"}},
                text:{presentation:'Kebab Tacos, assiettes ...',opening_time:"Ouvert 7j/7j de 10h00 à 21h00"}},
                {id:"004",code:"100002",name:"Oh My Kebab","cnc":{id:3,url:"react-amulet.com"},address:"21 Avenue Jean Mermoz",postalcode:"69002",city:"Lyon",
                media:{logo:{small:"https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0f/05/71/6f/notre-logo.jpg",big:"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/Fs6ZHRp6LAogqxJrHRVmnEXH77OoKieYYf43E5bDcWrlDjpJoqWtsAYCvicF3fMc_F88oIHBVdc80_LCn4HoX3ZKRP1Y3Ysl6j1Bz8N2I8gJ0uZzLVG5970g8o87bCUee3pvZg"}},
                text:{presentation:'Kebab Tacos, assiettes ...',opening_time:"Ouvert 7j/7j de 10h00 à 21h00"}},

            ]
            
            var outpout = document.getElementById('output')
            outpout.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data)
        })();
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is impossible to answer without seeing your api code

Comment: my api code is just what is inside the .text() its just a simple html file with the script, my API is the var data = [ ] inside script tag

Comment: You API is returning an HTML and not a JSON view-source:https://api--food.web.app/

Comment: If that's this static code, just replace it by a JSON representing your `data`